# Appending data from a dataframe to a list- 'string indicies must be integers' in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, integer

Was wondering if you could provide some help. Basically, I have to amend rows from this dataframe into a list and it depends on values in a certain column being greater than 0. Here's what I did so far:

```
import pandas as pd
houseprices = pd.read_csv('https://tf-assets-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/tf-curric/data-science/houseprices.csv')
```

I'll then get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-5bd425210138> in <module>()
      1 houses_with_porches = []
      2 for house in houseprices:
----> 3   if house['openporchsf'] > 0:
      4     houses_with_porches.append(house)

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

This is confusing me because when I do convert the column with `pd.to_numeric` and put it in the for loop I get the same error. I also have tried stripping and blank spaces and the original column looks to be in integers so I am unsure on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try `for house in houseprices: print(house)` and check the output, and you'll understand the error (hint, it's the column headers)

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over a DataFrame you just get back the column names. This can be confusing. So you're trying to index into a string when you do `house['openporchsf']`.

Instead do:

```
houses_with_porches = []
for idx,house in houseprices.iterrows():
    if house['openporchsf'] > 0:
        houses_with_porches.append(house)
```

If I may make a suggestion, though, you might wish to keep your data in another, smaller DataFrame like this:

```
houses_with_porches = houseprices[houseprices['openporchsf'] > 0]
```

Comment: hmmm the first one brought me back an empty list but the second dataframe one worked, thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome. The second one is the better option anyway. Cheers.